# How to assign JSON data into UILabel using SwiftyJSON in Swift 3.0 ?

Tags: json, swift3, xcode8, swifty-json

This is my JSON data

```
{
    "Number":"ID001",
    "Password":"1111",
    "Email":"email@gmail.com"
}
```

Currently i'm using SwiftyJSON to print specific JSON output in X Code. So far i managed to print email value specifically. But i'm not sure how to **display email value in UILabel emailLbl**.

The code as below.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var emailLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/get.php")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }
            else {
                guard let data = data else {
                    print("data was nill ?")
                    return
                }

                let json = JSON(data: data)
                print(json["email"].string!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Does Anyone have any idea how ?

Thanks.

Comment: `emailLbl.text = json["email"].string ?? ""`

Comment: Thanks :) . it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   let json = JSON(data: data)
   print(json["email"].string!)
   self.emailLbl.text = json["email"].string!
```

Comment: Why using SwiftyJSON at all if you don't use its features? There's a `.stringValue` property which is already unwrapped. Whereas `.string` is the optional getter and shouldn't be force unwrapped (use `if let` or `guard let`). Or don't use SwiftyJSON altogether for such simple tasks... :)